# Script works on Windows Server 2003 but returns error 0x8007000e on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, apache, perl, storage, powerpoint

I've a Perl script that forks in order to use `Win32::OLE` to extract PNGs of slides from a Powerpoint presentation.  I'm in the process of migrating it from my old server (Windows Server 2003) to a new server (Windows Server 2012).  The script works fine on the old server (which has Microsoft Office 2010) but on the new server (with Microsoft Office 2016), the script bombs with an error about there not being enough storage available:

```
Win32::OLE(0.1712) error 0x8007000e: "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation"
```

I've found quite a few references to this error code, but none particularly useful.  Whilst [this Microsoft support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/890425/you-receive-a-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-complete-this-operati) says what the problem is and what to do to fix it, I have no idea why this is suddenly an issue now I'm moving to a different server and it doesn't seem to apply to my situation.

The new server has loads of spare disk space and RAM, so there should be plenty to go around.  (The old server has far less of both, but that still works.)

Could this be something to do with the new server being 64-bit?

Could it be because of the differing versions of Office?

Could Apache or Perl be configured differently by default than when installed on the old server?  (It's a new installation of each, but from the same source as on the old server, and I can't find any configuration that limits memory.)

One interesting point that leads me to believe that it's something to do with the script running via Apache (v2.4.27) is that if I run it from the command line (requiring a minor modification), it works fine.  Apache runs as a service and I've tried running it as the same user for which it works on the command line, and that has no impact.

I've run out of places to look and things to try now, so any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE (21 August): Since nobody seems to have any ideas, I refactored my code slightly so that it gets called via a scheduled task.  That works fine, supporting my theory that it's something to do with it being run via Apache.  I'll keep this question open, partly in case a solution is presented and partly in case my workaround can help anyone else who has a similar problem.